# Using JobExecutionDecider with createOptionFlowUsingSteps

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using `createOptionFlowUsingSteps` in my `JobConfiguration` and I've got 2 flows defined.

1. The first flow should always execute
2. If the first flow produces an empty output file, the job should end
3. If the file has contents, the second flow should begin

**PROBLEM**: the job ***is*** ending if the file is **empty** but if the file has contents, the job repeats the first flow and never performs the second flow.

## Config

As you can see, I have `startSteps` and `endSteps`. Thank you for the help!

```
List<Step> startSteps = Arrays.asList( //
                shp294SetupStep, // 0
                deleteFileStep, // 1
                callM204Step// 2
        );

        List<Step> endSteps = Arrays.asList( //
                putFtpStep, // 0
                cdtx500SetupStep, // 1
                getFtpStep, // 2
                callCobolStep, // 3
                callSystemwareStep, //4
                cdtx510SetupStep, // 5
                getFtpStep, // 6
                callCobolStep, // 7
                putFtpStep// 8
        );

        List<Integer> emptyFileRequiredSteps = Arrays.asList(0);
        List<Integer> requiredSteps = Arrays.asList(1, 5);
        Flow startStepFlow = shpcdwrdStepHelper.createOptionalFlowUsingSteps(startSteps, emptyFileRequiredSteps);
        Flow endStepFlow = shpcdwrdStepHelper.createOptionalFlowUsingSteps(endSteps, requiredSteps);

        return jobFactory.get(JOB_NAME) //
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) //
                .listener(new JobResultListener()) //
                .start(startStepFlow) //
                .next(optionalFlowDecider()).on(OptionalFlowDecider.ON_EMPTY_FILE).end() //
                .from(optionalFlowDecider()).on(FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED.getName()).to(endStepFlow)
                .build() //
                .build(); //
```

Answer (score 0):

In your flow definition, you should use the `flow` method to start your flow and define all outcomes from each transition, something like:

```
return jobFactory.get(JOB_NAME) //
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) //
                .listener(new JobResultListener()) //
                .flow(startStepFlow) //
                .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(optionalFlowDecider())
                .from(optionalFlowDecider()).on(OptionalFlowDecider.ON_EMPTY_FILE).end() //
                .from(optionalFlowDecider()).on(FlowExecutionStatus.COMPLETED.getName()).to(endStepFlow)
                .build() //
                .build(); //
```

Comment: For some reason when I add `.flow(startStepFlow)` , I get the error `The method flow(Step) in the type JobBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Flow)` Thanks for your help Mahmoud!

Comment: I ended up using a `JobExecutionListener` and set `jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.COMPLETED);` on an empty file